# How to select and zoom in features from a QGIS Python Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I'm very new to Python. I'm trying to find a way to select and zoom to the features from a QGIS layer.

I've created a plugin and built a custom form. I have 3 values from the form which I need to place in a query but as I'm new, I don't know how.

```
aExchange = self.dlg.EXCHANGE_1141_CODE.currentText()
aPCP = self.dlg.BT_OBJECT_CLASS.currentText()
aObject = self.dlg.BT_OBJECT_ID.text()
```

The filter on the Attribute table is like this:

```
"EXCHANGE_1141_CODE" = 'IH' AND "BT_OBJECT_CLASS" = 'PCP' AND "BT_OBJECT_ID" = '10'
```

I've tried:

```
alayer.SetSubSetString ('EXCHANGE_1141_CODE = \'IH\'')
```

but this seems to just change the filter on the layer source which isn't what I want.

I want to be able to search for a feature and go to it. How can I do it with PyQGIS?

Answer (score 10):

Follow these 5 steps in the QGIS Python console:

1. Get the layer reference (I assume the layer is at the top of the ToC):

   `l = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]`
2. Get a featureIterator from an expression:

   `expr = QgsExpression( "\"EXCHANGE_1141_CODE\"='IH'" )
   it = l.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )`
3. Build a list of feature Ids from the result obtained in 2.:

   `ids = [i.id() for i in it]`
4. Select features with the ids obtained in 3.:

   `l.setSelectedFeatures( ids )`
5. Zoom to selected features:

   `iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()`

I've tested this procedure in QGIS v.2.6.

Answer (score 5):

After selecting the features, 'Zoom to Selection' can also be done by the following code:

```
eMenu = self.iface.viewMenu()
eMenu.actions() [12].trigger()
```