# store QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures() result in order to speed up subsequent feature requests

Tags: pyqgis-3

I'm doing a lot (really a lot) of feature requests on a vector layer. These requests are capsuled in iterations and functions, so no way of reducing the total number of requests.

Although I consider the #1 tip concerning `QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures()` - use a specific request whenever possible ([Why use QgsFeatureRequest() when iterating?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131984/why-use-qgsfeaturerequest-when-iterating)) - I end up with low performance and `cProfile` tells me the bottleneck is still the feature request.

Btw, using `layer.getFeature(fid)` instead of

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid)
feature = next(layer.getFeatures(request))
```

doesn't make any difference.

How do I speed up my feature requests, when I know each feature is called lots of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is a dictionary called `lineIndex`, with the format `{fid: QgsFeature}`:

```
self.lineIndex={}
lines = layer.getFeatures()
for line in lines:  # every line
    self.lineIndex[line.id()] = line
```

Now I can acess any feature in no time by `feat = self.lineIndex[fid]`.

For more complex questions, tuples as dictionary keys could be considered (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205141/search-dictionary-for-matching-values).