# Select features and zoom to selection on standalone QGis application

Tags: pyqgis, zoom, standalone

I'm trying to select and zoom on selected features on standalone QGis application.
Selection seems to work, console shows me list of selected items and they are exactly I expected.

```
ids = []
for f in kt.getFeatures():
 if f['KatastriNumber']==k_n:
     ids.append(f.id)
     print f['eraldus']
kt.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```

But zooming to selection does not work. I have tried many code samples i found from internet. None of them doesnt zoom to selected. Can only zoom to entire layer with:

canvas.setExtent(kt.extent())

I tried to make a box with command:

```
box = kt.boundingBoxOfSelected()
canvas.setExtent(box)
```

This gives no result.Then I tried with command

```
canvas.zoomToSelected(kt)
```

also no result.
How to tell app that some features from layer are selected?

Comment: Did you try `canvas.zoomToSelected()` (with no argument) already? Also, it should be `f.id()` (with parenthesis) to properly call the id method. You can check `ck.selectedFeatureCount()` to make sure you have selected features. This post tells you how to use expressions to select features and then zoom to the selection: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91011/how-to-select-and-zoom-in-features-from-a-qgis-python-plugin/126532#126532

Comment: I tried canvas.zoomToSelected(). still zoomed to location last opened in project. kt.selectedFeatureCount() displays 5

Comment: Great that you solved it. If you want, post the answer and mark it as accepted to properly close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It required once more canvas refresh to zoom to right place.
Final working block:

```
ids = []
for f in kt.getFeatures():
 if f['KatastriNumber']==k_n:
     ids.append(f.id())
print ids 
kt.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
nt= kt.selectedFeatureCount()
print "Valitud eraldusi: %d"%nt
box = kt.boundingBoxOfSelected()
kt.setSelectedFeatures([])
kt.loadNamedStyle(stiil)
canvas.setExtent(box)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.zoomScale(10000)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()
```