# Comparing values between two fields in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm building a graphical model in QGIS 3.4 to check if a point feature with a specific value in the `A` field is within a polygon with the same value in `B` field.

The image displays the draft of the model.
[image]
I set two vector layers as input (point layer and polygon layer), then I added the algorithm "Join attributes by location". After I tried to use "Select by attribute" to compare the attribute values between two fields and I continued adding "Extract selected feature" algorithm.

My issue is in "Select by attribute" part, I don't know what I need to write in the "Value" field or if there are other solutions to compare the value of the two fields.
[image]

I found this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340599/extracting-features-with-equal-field-value-using-graphical-modeler-of-qgis) that uses actions but I prefer Graphical Modeler.

Comment: Are you absolutely locked to QGIS3.4? There would probably be a much easier way to do this with the newer `overlay_contains` or `overlay_within` functions. You should be able to use the *Extract by expression* tool without even having to build a model, I think.

Comment: @GabrielC. at now I'm locked at QGIS 3.4 but it is useful to know that there are these new tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to use QGIS 3.4, I'll stay in the basic modeler. It can be as simple not using the *selection* algorithms, but rather the **Extract by expression** algorithm. Selecting features in a model doesn't always work perfectly and since creating new layers in memory doesn't leave a huge mess behind, extracting directly and using that extraction in subsequent algorithms usually works exactly the same way. Only what you actively save to a temporary layer or a file will remain. For your model, you can replicate this one with the following parameters for the Extract:

- **Input layer**: The result of *Join attributes by location*
- **Expression**: `"FieldA" = "FieldB"`
- **Matching features**: The layer you want to save

It shouldn't be more complicated than that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.